# Failed to load resource on web method AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I'm trying to use AJAX and calling web method like this in my code.

```
function generate_source(year_source, month_source) {
            var gData_source = '';
            if (year_source) {
                gData_source = [];
                gData_source[0] = year_source;
                gData_source[1] = month_source;
                console.log('first part');
            }
            else {
                var d_source = new Date();
                gData_source = [];
                gData_source[0] = d_source.getFullYear();
                gData_source[1] = d_source.getMonth() + 1;
                console.log('second part');


            }
            var jsonData_source = JSON.stringify({
                gData_source: gData_source
            });


            var ctx = document.getElementById("order_source").getContext('2d');
            $.ajax({

                url: "dashboard.aspx/getordersource",
                data: jsonData_source,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#loader_divsource").show();
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#loader_divsource").hide();
                    var chartLabel = eval(response.d[0]); //Labels
                    var chartData = eval(response.d[1]); //Data

                    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'doughnut',
                        data: {

                            labels: chartLabel,
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    type: 'doughnut',
                                    label: chartLabel,
                                    data: chartData,
                                    backgroundColor: [
                                         "#FF6384",
                                         "#36A2EB",
                                    ],
                                    hoverBackgroundColor: [
                                        "#FF6384",
                                        "#36A2EB",
                                    ]

                                }

                            ]
                        }
                    });

                }

            });


        }
        var d_source = new Date();
        gData_source = [];
        $('#year_source').val(d.getFullYear());
        $('#month_source').val(d.getMonth() + 1);
        generate_source('', '');
```

My web method is like this;

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> getordersource(List<int> gData)
    {
        DataSet ds = ws_db.get_Dataset_order_source();
        var returnData = new List<string>();

     ......
        return returnData;

    }
```

Whenever I try to run this data, my breakpoint for the web method is not hit.  Further, if i use the same method without data, i don't get this error. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Did you check your console for any errors?

Comment: yes, it gives me "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: What do you mean by "if i use the same method without data, i don't get this error"?

Comment: If I don't pass json data in the call and update my web method to take no parameters, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in this code :

```
var jsonData_source = JSON.stringify({
                gData_source: gData_source
            });
```

you are trying to serialize array with key value pair that it is become invalid. 
change to this :

```
var jsonData_source = JSON.stringify(gData_source);
```

also your web method should be like this :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.JSON)]
    // just return a string, not list, your JSON string should have contain all your enumerable in your string Data
    public static string getordersource(List<int> gData)
    {
        DataSet ds = ws_db.get_Dataset_order_source();
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var returnData = serializer.serialize(ds);

     ......
        return returnData;

    }
```

Hope it helps.